# How to fetch query only AFTER state is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm trying to query data from an api by passing it a breed and a sub-breed as arguments. I'm storing these values as state and updating them on button click.

Does anyone know how to query the data only AFTER the state has been updated? Because otherwise the arguments would be undefined and I'd get an error.

I tried putting the hook inside the handleClick function but I got an error telling me it was an invalid hook call.

Any ideas?

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import {
  useGetAllDogsQuery,
  useGetImageByBreedQuery,
} from "../features/api/apiSlice";
import { Button, ImageList } from "@mui/material";
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { Box, ImageListItem } from "@mui/material";

const SpecificBreed = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef("");
  const inputRef2 = useRef("");
  const [dogInfo, setDogInfo] = useState({
    subBreed: "",
    breed: "",
  });
  const { data, isSuccess } = useGetImageByBreedQuery(
    dogInfo.breed,
    dogInfo.subBreed
  );

  let images = [];

  function handleClick() {
    setDogInfo({
      subBreed: inputRef2.current,
      breed: inputRef.current.replace(/\s/g, ""),
    });
  }

  function handleChange(event) {
    inputRef.current = event.target.value;
  }

  function handleChange2(event) {
    inputRef2.current = event.target.value;
    console.log(inputRef2);
  }

  if (isSuccess) {
    let arrayCopy = {
      ...data.message,
    };
    Object.values(arrayCopy).map((image) => {
      if (image) {
        images.push(
          <ImageListItem
            key={
              image.includes("(")
                ? image.substring(0, image.length - 5) +
                  image.substring(image.length - 4, image.length)
                : image
            }
            cols={Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 2}
            rows={Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 2}
            sx={{
              "&.MuiImageListItem-root": {
                border: `2px solid black`,
              },
            }}
          >
            <img
              src={image.includes("xeshaBelka") ? "" : image}
              alt="dog"
              loading="lazy"
            />
          </ImageListItem>
        );
      }
    });
  }
  return (
    <Box
      width="100%"
      display="flex"
      justifyContent="center"
      marginTop="350px"
      flexDirection="column"
      gap="5rem"
      alignItems="center"
      sx={{}}
    >
      <Box
        width="50%"
        display="flex"
        justifyContent="center"
        alignItems="center"
        flexDirection="column"
        gap="20px"
      >
        <TextField
          variant="outlined"
          label="Enter a breed..."
          sx={{ width: "100%" }}
          inputRef={inputRef}
          onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
        />
        <TextField
          variant="outlined"
          label="Enter a sub-breed..."
          sx={{ width: "100%" }}
          inputRef={inputRef2}
          onChange={(event) => handleChange2(event)}
        />
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          sx={{ width: "100%" }}
          onClick={handleClick}
        >
          Find Pictures
        </Button>
      </Box>
      <ImageList variant="masonry" cols={4} gap={8} sx={{ p: "1rem" }}>
        {images}
      </ImageList>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default SpecificBreed;
```

The API's running fine, I tried it with hard-coded values but here it is:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

export const apiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: "api",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "https://dog.ceo/api/",
  }),
  tagTypes: ["Dogs"],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getAllDogs: builder.query({
      query: () => `breeds/list/all`,
      //   providesTags: (result) =>
      //     result ? result.map(({ id }) => ({ type: "Dogs", id })) : [],
    }),
    getRandomImage: builder.query({
      query: (number) => `breeds/image/random/${number}`,
    }),
    getImageByBreed: builder.query({
      query: ({ breed, subBreed }) =>
        `breed/${breed}/${subBreed}/images/random`,
    }),
  }),
});

export const {
  useGetAllDogsQuery,
  useGetRandomImageQuery,
  useGetImageByBreedQuery,
} = apiSlice;
```

Comment: Did you try `useEffect`?

Comment: I tried it, I got the same react error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

Comment: Then... you are not using it in the body of the function component... Thats the problem... Can you add your `useEffect` full code?

Comment: Yeah I updated it

Comment: There is no any useEffect in your code

Answer (score 0):

You can use useEffect if you want to provide a side effect if there is a change in state.

example:

```
const [state, setState] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
  if(!state) return
  // this is the place for the function that will be given a side effect
  getData(); //example
},[state])
```

if the `state` changes, then the function `getData()` inside useEffect will change. if `state` is `null`, `getData()` will not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally run queries when specifying a `skip` option. Skip running the query when the params are not available.

See:

- [Conditional Fetching](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/conditional-fetching) for details
- [useQuery](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#skiptoken)

Examples

```js
const { data, isSuccess } = useGetImageByBreedQuery(
  dogInfo,
  { skip: !dogInfo.breed && !dogInfo.subBreed }
);
```

Or using the `skipToken`.

```js
import { skipToken } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

...

const { data, isSuccess } = useGetImageByBreedQuery(
  dogInfo.breed && dogInfo.subBreed ? dogInfo : skipToken,
);
```